Help me calculate
Calculate $\prod_{a \in \mathbb Z_p} (a^2+a+1)$  where $p \equiv -1 \pmod 3$ and $p$ is an odd prime number.
I tried simply putting some prime number and was getting 3 everytime, however it won't help calculate the whole product.

What did you get for the product when you tried some example values of $p$?

I was getting 3 everytime.

Hint:  $(a^3-1)=(a-1)(a^2+a+1)$.

Perhaps state what $\mathbb{Z_p}$ is.  Is it the the $p$-adic integers, so this is an uncountable product?  It seems strange to use $\mathbb p$ and not $p$ in the subscript.

Apply Lulu's hint and the fact that $a\mapsto a^3$ is a permutation of the elements of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ (you prove that it is, otherwise no good). Set aside $a=1$.

$\prod\limits_{a\not\equiv1}\left[(a-1)(a^2+a+1)\right]=\prod\limits_{a\not\equiv1}\left[a^3-1\right]=\prod\limits_{a\not\equiv1}\left[a-1\right]$, so $\prod\limits_{a\not\equiv1}\left[a^2+a+1\right]\equiv1$

If you find the answers helpful you should upvote them and accept the one that you find most helpful/ helped you solve the problem. This is how this sites works. It's a way of saying "thank you for your help".

The answer is $\equiv3$ for $p=2$ as well

Sadly, now can only accept an answer. When I'll get 15 reputation I'll upvote everyone for sure.
Edit: I upvoted everyone.

Avoid phrases like I don't even know where to start. This will look like a no-clue question. You are supposed to show some work yourself.

You could edit your question to include your comment “I was getting $3$ every time”

First lets notice that
$$\prod_{a\in \mathbb{Z}_p, a\neq 1} (a-1) \equiv -1$$
that is because every element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has its inverse except for $p-1\equiv -1$.
Then (using @lulu hint) $a^3-1 = (a-1)(a^2+a+1) $,
$$\left(\prod_{a\in \mathbb{Z}_p,a\neq 1} (a-1) \right)\left(\prod_{a \in \mathbb Z_p} (a^2+a+1)\right)=3\prod_{a\in \mathbb{Z}_p,a\neq 1} (a^3-1)$$
and the product that we search would be congruent to
$$-3\prod_{a\in \mathbb{Z}_p,a\neq 1} (a^3-1).$$
and with a similar argument of the wilson theorem ($a^3-1$ is a permutation of the elements) you can conclude that
$$-3\prod_{a\in \mathbb{Z}_p,a\neq 1} (a^3-1) \equiv -3(-1) \equiv 3.$$

Thank you! I'll write that down step by step to understand better.

happy to help (i modifide it a little since i had multiplied by 0 (a=1)), it can be fixed multipling by the term given by $a=1$ ie $(1^2+1+1)\equiv 3$ and then continuing the same way.

So, it seems that the initial answer 3 was right? But it has no proof that it is for whole product?

@MakutaJK it is for the whole product, we just take the term given by a = 1 and multiplied first, this is because $(a-1)$ would be 0 and multipling by that woul "kill" the multiplication, and that is why we don't

Can you comment please on how is this enough that $a^3-1$ is a permutation of the elements and thus we can use Wilson's theorem? Is it just because of $a↦a^3$? Feels like there is more to it and the $p≡-1 (mod 3)$ plays the role.

the idea is that in modulo $p$ almost every element has multiplicative inverse that is diferent of it self, minus p-1, then if you multiply, every element in the group every element and its inverse would be in there and for that they will multiply 1, so $\prod_{a\in \mathbb{Z}_p}a \equiv (1)(22^{-1})(33^{-1})\dots(p-1) \equiv 1\cdot 1 \cdots (p-1) \equiv p-1.$

Got it! Thanks!

I see no need for Wilson's theorem here.
$\prod\limits_{a\in\mathbb F_p,a\not\equiv1}\left[(a-1)(a^2+a+1)\right]=\prod\limits_{a\in\mathbb F_p,a\not\equiv1}\left[a^3-1\right]=\prod\limits_{a\in\mathbb F_p,a\not\equiv1}\left[a-1\right]$,
since $a\mapsto a^3$ is invertible since $3\nmid p-1$
(and at this point we're excluding $1^3=1,$ so $a-1\not\equiv0),\;$
so $\prod\limits_{a\in\mathbb F_p, a\not\equiv1}\left[a^2+a+1\right]\equiv1.\;$  Therefore $\prod\limits_{a\in \mathbb F_p}\left[a^2+a+1\right]=1^2+1+1=3.$

First working $mod$ $p$.
$$ P_p \triangleq \prod_{i=1}^{p} (i^2+i+1)$$
$$ P_p =\prod_{i=1}^{p} \dfrac{(i^3-1)}{i-1}=3\prod_{i=2}^{p} \dfrac{(i^3-1)}{i-1}=3\dfrac{\prod_{i=2}^{p}(i^3-1)}{(p-1)!}$$
Using Wilson's theorem ($p$ odd),    $ \ \ (p-1)!=-1 \ [p]$,
Then :
$$ P_p =-3 \prod_{i=2}^{p}(i^3-1)$$
Using $a \to a^3$ being a permutation of $Z_p$ as suggested in the comments could you end from here ?

I'll try now to do it, thanks a lot to you and others!

Also, wanted to ask: is there a reason to why you replaced $a$ with $i$?

It is just an habit, that with incremental index, I put $i$, but $a$ stands also because its an arbitrary variable.
